# Wired connection being dropped

Tags: networking, ethernet, arch-linux, arm

I have an ARMv7 microcomputer (based on Freescale IMX6) that works as media server, running on Archlinux. The last couple of weeks i've been having issues with the wired connection (eth0), it drops out of the blue. There is no led activity in the router at all.

This can be solved by resetting the server. It never dropped when i was ssh'd to it tho.

Any idea about what tests to make in order to isolate the problem?

Thanks.

NEWS!

After monitoring for half an hour via Serial, the connection dropped and dmesg got me:

```
[ 2446.512636] fec 2188000.ethernet eth0: MDIO read timeout
[ 2449.518071] libphy: 2188000.ethernet:00 - Link is Down
```

When manually restarting the netctl profile:

```
[gabriel@KRAKEN ~] sudo netctl restart wired     
[ 4628.956096] fec 2188000.ethernet eth0: Freescale FEC PHY driver                  [Atheros 8035 ethernet] (mii_bus:phy_addr=2188000.ethernet:00, irq=-1)
[ 4628.980669] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[ 4634.965091] libphy: 2188000.ethernet:00 - Link is Up - 100/Full
[ 4635.001893] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[ 4641.010042] libphy: 2188000.ethernet:00 - Link is Down
[ 4644.030879] libphy: 2188000.ethernet:00 - Link is Up - 100/Full
[ 4646.067933] libphy: 2188000.ethernet:00 - Link is Up - 10/Full
```

Comment: Anything in the system log or dmesg (you'll often find hardware-related errors there) ? To quickly look at the latest items in dmesg just run `dmesg | tail`.

Comment: that might be a NIC issue, or driver issue. I'd try updating drivers first - you don't have a lot of options on those if it is hardware issue. I've seen issues where a bad cable can have similar symptoms as well.

Comment: I connected my device by serial to my desktop and found had some issues with eth0, the device was not up. I had to add some timeout parameters to the wired profile on netctl and now the connection is up again after reboot. However, this is a new issue. I found nothing but "device is not ready" on dmesg.

I'll keep the device connected by serial a couple of hours to see if can replicate the dropout and then check again dmesg.

Comment: "device is not ready" may indicate an issue with the driver talking to the card - maybe a firmware issue on the card? still could be a driver issue as well.

Comment: New stuff added guys.

Comment: If it does that repeatedly then it is a flapping iface. The link down indicates a break on layer 2 which usually is a physical issue - that can be cable, NIC or switch port. Try moving to a different switch port. If the issue continues, try replacing the cable. If that doesn't work, it is probably the NIC.

Comment: No, had nothing to do with the hardware and suspected. Just installed a new kernel and problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Installed a new kernel and problem solved.